# SPBT2632C2A Operating Voltage Related

Tags: power, bluetooth, 3.3v

Is the [SPBT2632C2A](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/DM00048919.pdf) compatible with a 3.3v Logic System? I was thinking of using it with a BeagleBoneBlack, Absolute maximum rating is rated for 5.5v, So i can feed the module power from a LM1117-3.3 and drive the Tx/Rx Pins directly from the beaglebone's gpio??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recommended operating conditions: -

[image]

Page 10 of the data sheet.

This does not mean that you can power it from 3V3 and feed logic signals that are 5V compatible. Use a potential divider to drop 5V logic signals to the device. Using the table above, you need to drop the logic level to nominally 2.1 volts although the spec isn't very clear.

Comment: the beaglebone's output is 3.3v, i said only the maximum was rated for 5v, so i have to be lower than that for sure, and 3.3v is 2.2v lower.

I couldn't find any application circuits for that module so thought of asking it here, maybe someone who used these modules woudl have an idea. 

So you recommend using a 2.5v Source with a 3.3 -> 2.1 logic converter?

Comment: @user2967920 I'm not recommending any specific supply voltage but if i were to recommend one it'd be 2V5. Use a logic convertor or resistors for the inputs to the device.

Comment: Allright, 
Page 13 of the Datasheet says Tx and Rx are 5v Tolerant, so i'll use a LM1117-3.3 with a voltage divider and drop the input supply to 2.5v, that should do the job.

Comment: I don't think a fixed voltage regulator of 3v3 and a resistor divider is going to work very well, can't you get an adjustable regulator to work directly at 2.5 volts like the LM1117-2.5?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, and i found a LM2596 Based module with an adjustable output lying in the inventory. So till we make the production PCB's this one should do the trick for testing and dev. 
Thanks Andy!